# having issue trying to "grunt server" RangeError:

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman

https://gist.github.com/YonasBerhe/fbbdfb0c30edb96a882b

I have checked util.js^^: line 35 can't find the error.

util.js:35
  var str = String(f).replace(formatRegExp, function(x) {
                      ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#why-am-i-getting-a-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error

Comment: Like @taha-paksu said, usually this is an issue with redefining a grunt task name. Can you show us your `Gruntfile.js`?